# Experiencing an error during code analysis for CASA requirements

Tags: android, react-native

The technology I utilized is a React Native mobile application.

Encountering an error while executing the command to run a Docker file, it yields the following error message:

[Got error from NIX package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTmWq.png)

The command leading to the error is:-

```
docker run casascan m gitlab:fluidattacks/universe@trunk /skims scan {App Repo Name}/config.yaml
```

and my folder structure is :--  scan

1. scan>>Application Repo
2. scan>>docker file
3. scan>>Application Repo>>config.yaml
   [Folder structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsHzP.png)

Here is my config.yaml file code

```
# Description:
#   Pick a name you like, normally the name of the repository.
# Example:
namespace: OWASP

# Description:
#   Omit if you want pretty-printed results,
#   Set to a path if you want CSV results.
# Optional:
#   Yes
# Example:
output:
  file_path: ./Fluid-Attacks-Results.csv
  format: CSV

# Description:
#   Working directory, normally used as the path to the repository.
# Example:
working_dir: ./mobileclient

# Description:
#   SAST for source code.
# Example:
sast:
  # Description:
  #   Target files used in the analysis.
  # Example:
  include:
    # Absolute path
    - .
    # Relative path to `working_dir`
    - .

# Description:
#  Reversing checks for Android APKs.
apk:
  # Description:
  #   Target files used in the analysis.
  # Example:
  include:
    # Absolute paths
    - KuntoResearch\android\app\release\app-release.apk
    # - /app/app-arm-debug.apk
    # - /app/app-x86-debug-Android5.apk
    # - /app/app-x86-debug.apk


# Description:
#   Findings to analyze.
#   The complete list of findings can be found here:
#   https://gitlab.com/fluidattacks/universe/-/blob/trunk/skims/manifests/findings.lst
# Optional:
#   Yes, if not present all security findings will be analyzed.
# Example:
# Description:
#   Language to use, valid values are: EN, ES.
# Optional:
#   Yes, defaults to: EN.
language: EN
```

Taking a reference of this file :- https://appdefensealliance.dev/casa/tier-2/ast-guide/static-scan

Answer (score 3):

You didn't paste the full error message (you should always copy and paste *all* the text so it's more searchable). I suspect your original error was:

```
error: attribute 'attrPaths' missing
```

If you're trying to run this container for the purposes of a CASA scan then [this article is out of date](https://appdefensealliance.dev/casa/tier-2/ast-guide/static-scan).

Instead, read and follow https://docs.fluidattacks.com/tech/scanner/standalone/casa/ .